# Is there a way to extend a blade template with a variable name in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working on a site that have 2 different main templates but sometimes the views are the same, example:

kk.waiting.blade.php:

```
@extends('kk.template')
@section('content')
 Waiting For Approval
@stop
```

cc.waiting.blade.php

```
@extends('cc.template')
@section('content')
 Waiting For Approval
@stop
```

I wonder if there is a way to use a variable like this:

waiting.blade.php

```
@extends({{$var}}'.template')
@section('content')
 Waiting For Approval
@stop
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
@extends($var. '.template');
```

Don't need to use the {{}} since I'm already inside php tags by the @